# Oracle view or With Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, view, with-statement

Is there is any difference between oracle view and WITH clause? I am asking this because I have written an SQL using WITH clause. The behaviour I am seeing as the SQL within WITH clause is not giving me a consistent output.

For example, the SQL within WITH clause has to generate 20 records and provide these 20 records to the other SQL. The trend I am observing that someday 20 records and someday 18 or 17 and even 14. On manually running this SQL I get 20 records.

```
with subject as (
    select subject_id
    from report_card
    where card_id = 100
)
select *
from student stud,
     subject s
where s.subject_id = stud.subject_id;
```

To overcome my problem, I thought of writing WITH clause statement in a view.

TIA

Comment: The result of the query won't be any different with a CTE or a view (barring a bug, of course). Is the content of the table you're joining the CTE to changing, maybe?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query output depends on this condition ***s.subject_id = stud.subject_id*** and I guess, due to this it is changing. May be the matched records in the subject table, are less.

You can also use the following query to get the same output.

```
select r.subject_id,s.* from report_card r join subject s on 
s.subject_id = r.subject_id and r.card_id=100;
```